# AngularJS ng-repeat and Semantic UI Accordion doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui

I am trying to use an ng-repeat inside a Semantic UI accordion. However, once I included ng-repeat inside the div tag with the accordion class, the accordion doesn't open nor close anymore. Clicking it doesn't do anything.

**The accordion works properly here:**

```
<div class="ui styled accordion">
    <div class="title"> 
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Filename 
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <a>File Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The accordion breaks once I include ng-repeat:**

```
<div ng-repeat="file in files" class="ui styled accordion">
    <div class="title"> 
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Filename 
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <a>File Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to include the ng-repeat inside the accordion, and I need the accordion to do what it's supposed to do. Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried <div class="ui styled accordion"><div ng-repeat="file in files" ><div class="title">

Comment: ooh, that did the trick. Thank you! @JonathanAnctil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="ui styled accordion">
    <div ng-repeat="file in files">
        <div class="title"> 
        ...
```

ng-repeat and semantic ui needs to be separated